# Execute shell commands

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, native

I developed a standalone executable for Android, and I try to execute some shell commands in the c++ code.
I firstly tried to use popen and it worked on some devices but there is a specific device which fails.
exec and fork also not working on this device and even "system()" doesn't.
I understand the libc of Android (bionic) may not include these calls but I can't find a generic way to execute some shell commands which works in all of my devices.
I also couldn't find any documentation about it in the NDK documentation.
That is very weird because Android Java API expose the "Runtime.exec()" function which works great, then why it's so hard to do it in the native side. 
EDIT: 
errno of system is "Success".

Comment: That's weird. Do you know how *exactly* does it fail? What's the errno? Is that your device, or a crash report from some unknown user?

Comment: It's one of my devices , it's a galaxy s6.